# Redirect for non www to www and http to https

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, web, https

I am working on a redirect code (that will work) for my website (it is hosted on an Apache server). What I require is a code that will redirect ALL traffic from non www to www as well as All traffic from HTTP to HTTPS.

I have tried many codes but they either do not work fully or I get stuck on a redirect loop. So basically I want a code that will redirect:

```
http:// .example.com  AND  http://www.example.com  AND  https://.example.com
TO
https://www.example.com
```

Comment: really pulling my hair out with this

Answer (score 1):

Use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: unfortunately this code causes a redirect loop and therefore does not work for me

Comment: No, the problem is not in this code. You must have a problem with the site configuration. Or if you have other lines in your .htaccess...

Comment: hi again, there are no other lines in the code and my web hosts are telling me that the issue lies in the .htaccess

Comment: this whole thing is just a nightmare... I do appreciate you help however